# Insert NULL into postrgesql timestamp

Tags: database, postgresql, csv

I'm trying to insert values from csv file into my postgresql database.
This is my table:

```
CREATE TABLE AllocatedEICDetail (
  Id                                    SERIAL NOT NULL, 
  EntityCreatedAt                       timestamp(34) with time zone NOT NULL, 
  EntityModifiedAt                      timestamp(34) with time zone NOT NULL, 
  MRID                                  varchar(250), 
  DocStatusValue                        varchar(250), 
  AttributeInstanceComponent            varchar(250), 
  LongNames                             varchar(250), 
  DisplayNames                          varchar(250), 
  LastRequestDateAndOrTime              timestamp(7), 
  DeactivateRequestDateAndOrTime        timestamp(7), 
  MarketParticipantStreetAddressCountry varchar(250), 
  MarketParticipantACERCode             varchar(250), 
  MarketParticipantVATcode              varchar(250), 
  Description                           varchar(255), 
  EICParentMarketDocumentMRID           varchar(250), 
  ELCResponsibleMarketParticipantMRID   varchar(250), 
  IsDeleted                             bool NOT NULL, 
  CONSTRAINT PK_AllocatedEICDetail 
    PRIMARY KEY (Id));
```

and the data I want to insert:

```
Id;EntityCreatedAt;EntityModifiedAt;MRID;DocStatusValue;AttributeInstanceComponent;LongNames;DisplayNames;LastRequestDateAndOrTime;DeactivateRequestDateAndOrTime;MarketParticipantStreetAddressCountry;MarketParticipantACERCode;MarketParticipantVATcode;Description;EICParentMarketDocumentMRID;ELCResponsibleMarketParticipantMRID;IsDeleted
47677;2019-04-01 09:26:51.2053104 +00:00;2019-04-01 09:26:51.2053104 +00:00;10T-1001-10010AS;A05;International;Tie Line Koman-KosovoB;L_KOM-KOSB;2018-10-31 00:00:00.0000000;NULL;NULL;;NULL;Tieline;NULL;10XAL-KESH-----J;0
47678;2019-04-01 09:26:51.2053104 +00:00;2019-04-01 09:26:51.2053104 +00:00;24X-LE-TRADING-N;A05;International;LE Trading a.s.;LE-TRADING;2013-12-18 00:00:00.0000000;NULL;SK;;SK2023878747;Trade Responsible Party;NULL;NULL;0
```

But when I try to insert the csv file to pgAdmin 4 I get this error:

> ERROR:  invalid input syntax for type timestamp: "NULL"
>   CONTEXT:  COPY allocatedeicdetail, line 2, column deactivaterequestdateandortime: "NULL"

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message implies you have a literal "NULL" (string) in your input data. You probably should try replacing those with empty values like shown below:

```
47677;2019-04-01 09:26:51.2053104 +00:00;2019-04-01 09:26:51.2053104 +00:00;10T-1001-10010AS;A05;International;Tie Line Koman-KosovoB;L_KOM-KOSB;2018-10-31 00:00:00.0000000;;;;;Tieline;;10XAL-KESH-----J;0
```